# Difficulty on understanding the proof of Mobius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This proof is obtained from "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen

Claim: If $n \gt 1$, then $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)=0$

Proof: If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_l^{a_l}$, then $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)=\sum_{(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_l)}\mu(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_l^{a_l})$, where the $\epsilon_i $ are $0$ or $1$.

Thus$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)=1-l+\binom{l}{2}-\binom{l}{3}+...+(-1)^l=(1-1)^l=0$$

My question is, how can $$\sum_{(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_l)}\mu(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_l^{a_l})=1-l+\binom{l}{2}-\binom{l}{3}+...+(-1)^l$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of square-free divisors with $k$ (distinct) out of $l$ primes is $l\choose k$.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unsure of how an equality follows, you can often see what's going on by working an example.  To calculate $\mu(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7)$, you have

$$\mu(1) = 1 = {4 \choose 0}$$ plus

$$\mu(2) + \mu(3) + \mu(5) + \mu(7) = -4 = -{4 \choose 1}$$

plus $$\mu(2 \cdot 3) + \mu(3 \cdot 5) + \mu(5 \cdot 7) + \mu(2 \cdot 7) + \mu (3 \cdot 7) + \mu(2 \cdot 5) =  6 =   {4 \choose 2}$$

plus $$\mu(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5) + \mu(3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7) + \mu(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7) + \mu(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7)= -4 = -{4 \choose 3}$$

plus $$\mu(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7) = 1 = {4 \choose 4}$$

In general, if you're calculating $\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \mu(n)$, and $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_l^{a_l}$, it comes down to choosing, for each $k \leq l$, a subset $\{m_1, ... , m_k\}$ of $\{1, ...  , l\}$ of $k$ distinct elements, and looking at $\mu(p_{m_1} \cdots p_{m_k})$.  For each $k$, there are ${l \choose k}$ such subsets.